# Creating a 2D array with three data types

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

In c# what is the best way of creating a 2D array which stores three data types? To create a 2D array I would usually use something like this

```
public GameObject [][] characters;
```

But I need to store an int in column 0, a gameObject in column 1 and a float in column 2. Is this possible in c# in unity? or should I be using a different datatype?

Comment: You cannot store more than one data types in one array. Either use multiple arrays, or a different data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to created a class or struct to store your data types, and then create and array of that new object.

It is far easier to encapsulate your different data types into one object. This will help with managing and moving the data around.

For instance:

```
public class Character
{
    public int MyInt = 0;
    public GameObject MyGameObject = null; // or whatever the default should be
    public float MyFloat = 0.0f;
}
```

Then create your array:

```
public Character[] characters;
```

Comment: Once you make an array of your class then what do you do? How do you add data to the array?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a structure (or class) with these threee fields: GameObject, float etc. Then make one dimension array of objects of this structure.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a class to hold these three objects;

```
class GameData {

    public int IntValue{ get; set; }
    public GameObject gameObject { get; set; }
    public float FloatValue { get; set; }
}
```

And then using a 1d array to hold them

```
GameData[] gameData;
```

You could probably achieve what you are looking for however by creating an object[][] array and using casts on the columns when they are called, but this would not be good practice